# Send clipboard content wrapped with two variables in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Using Autohotkey, Id like to concatenate the variable1, the clipboard contents, and variable2.

For example, if:

1. **variable1** = `https://example.com/somepage.php?command=details&reservationId=`
2. **clipboard contents** = `12345`
3. **variable2** = `&url=%2Fsomepage.php%3submit%3DSEARCH%26submit`

The expected result would be:

`https://example.com/somepage.php?command=details&reservationId=12345&url=%2Fsomepage.php%3submit%3DSEARCH%26submit`

---

The two methods shown below simply output **12345**

What am I doing wrong?

Attempt 1:

```
::hd-eurl::
 ClipSaved := ClipboardAll       ; get clipboard
 variable1:= "https://example.com/somepage.php?command=details&reservationId="
 variable2:= "&url=%2Fsomepage.php%3submit%3DSEARCH%26submit"
 ClipNew =  %variable1% . ClipSaved . %variable2%
 clipboard = ClipNew 
 ClipWait
 Send, ^v
 clipboard := ClipSaved       ; restore original clipboard
 return
```

Attempt 2:

```
::hd-eurl::
 Send ^c
 ClipSaved := ClipboardAll       ; get clipboard
 variable1= https://example.com/somepage.php?command=details&reservationId=
 variable2= &url=`%2Fsomepage.php`%3submit`%3DSEARCH`%26submit
 ClipNew =  variable1 . ClipSaved . variable2
 clipboard = ClipNew 
 ClipWait
 Send, ^v
 clipboard := ClipSaved       ; restore original clipboard
 return
```

Update (same results):

```
::hd-eurl::
 ClipSaved := ClipboardAll       ; get clipboard
 variable1:= "https://example.com/somepage.php?command=details&reservationId="
 variable2:= "&url=%2Fsomepage.php%3submit%3DSEARCH%26submit"
 ClipNew :=  variable1 . ClipSaved . variable2
 clipboard := ClipNew 
 ClipWait
 Send, ^v
 clipboard := ClipSaved       ; restore original clipboard
 return
```

---

**Working Solution**

This is how I finally got it working. However, Blauhirn's method in the selected answer is much simpler to use.

```
::hd-eurl::
 ClipSaved := ClipboardAll       ; store clipboard backup 
 variable1:= "https://example.com/somepage.php?command=details&reservationId="
 variable2=  %ClipBoard%
 ClipBoard =
 variable3:= "&url=%2Fsomepage.php%3submit%3DSEARCH%26submit"
 variable4:=  variable1 . variable2 . variable3
 Clipboard:= variable4
 ClipWait 
 Send, ^v
 Clipboard := ClipSaved       ; restore original clipboard
 return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `clipSaved` variable contains `clipboardAll`. [Documentation](http://ahkscript.org/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm) says:

> Variables to which ClipboardAll has been assigned are in binary format and thus will appear as gibberish when displayed with MsgBox or similar.

You have to use `clipboard` instead when assigning to `clipNew`, like

```
 ClipNew := variable1 . clipboard . variable2
```

Apart from that, I suggest you do not modify the contents of `clipboard` at all, for this is the most complicated way to do it. If you want to send something, just use the [send command](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Send.htm) on the very string instead of calling <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>:

```
::hd-eurl::
    variable1:= "https://example.com/somepage.php?command=details&reservationId="
    variable2:= "&url=%2Fsomepage.php%3submit%3DSEARCH%26submit"
    send % variable1 clipboard variable2
return
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Blauhrin. The only think I don't like about this method is that you have to wait for the script to type out the characters one by one. I'm hoping for a paste method which will send all of the text at once. That said, if I can't get that working, I will use and accept your solution.

Comment: as far as i know, this would only be necessary on slow computers / high workload. if thats not the case for you, try adding `setkeydelay, 0` at the top of your script so ahk's typing is instant

Comment: I finally got the original method working. However `setkeydelay, 0` does solve the slow typing issue and that makes your method much simpler. Thanks a lot, that typing out characters was really annoying!

Answer (score 1):

correct syntax is

```
ClipNew :=  variable1 . ClipSaved . variable2
```

or

```
ClipNew =  %variable1%%ClipSaved%%variable2%
```

[Variables and expressions](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Variables.htm)

also modify this line

```
clipboard := ClipNew
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same result. The output is only the original content of the clipboard, variable1 and 2 are not included in the output.

Comment: @DelightedD0D  also modify this line `clipboard := ClipNew `

Comment: you may want to clear the contents of clipboard before this line `clipboard := ClipNew`